# Implementing App Fabric for a SharePoint 2013 Application

Tags: sharepoint-2013, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am looking to replace Enterprise Lib. Cache with App Fabric distributed cache engine. I am going to be honest - I have no idea where to start. I know that SharePoint 2013 is already utilizing App Fabric so I my first concern is of configuration and overall architecture:

Can I use the same engine used by the SharePoint farm or do I have to rely on my own custom instance?